# Chihiro's name turning to Sen

Tags: plot-explanation, spirited-away

I don't understand the Japanese language or kanji, and this *might* be related to that.

As Chihiro gives her name to Yubaba, she writes 4 symbols in a piece of paper. 3 then fly away and she reads  the remaining symbol and calls her Sen.

### What was written in those symbols, and why did Chihiro's name turn out as Sen?

Comment: Question is still about the film only, so I am opening it. If anyone have counter argument, kindly express them on [respective meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/why-is-this-question-put-on-hold).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Answer: The remaining Kanji is what Chihiro's name will become if she was to stay in the spirit world.**

First thing first, her name in Japanese is this:

> **「荻野千尋（おぎの ちひろ）= Ogino Chihiro」**

Breaking it down,

> **「Last name 荻=おぎ=Ogi , 野=の=no 」**
>
> **「First name 千=ち=Chi , 尋=ひろ=hiro 」**

Her name does not have any meaning per se, but breaking down the Kanji,`千` In English `Chi` or `sen`, which means `1000` in English. The second Kanji `尋` , `tazuneru` or `hiro` means to `search` or `inquire`.

And just for a bit of trivia non relating to this question, when she signs the contract she makes a mistake and sign the first kanji as this：
This Kanji is not used in Japanese BTW

[image]

The reason for this was the longer she was to stay in the land of the dead the more she would forget about the living world, her making a mistake of her name is the first time we see her displaying this.

Onto the question about why the Kanji **「千, せん = sen」** remained. Does this mean anything? From a Japanese language point of view, no it doesn't. But, did **Miyazaki Hayao** want this to mean something, I don't know???

I am guessing this is what you were talking about,

[image]

Unfortunately this web page [千と千尋の神隠し【謎解き・解釈】～宮崎駿が伝えたかった事～](http://rinrism.com/maxim/anime/senchihi#i) is all in Japanese and the translator does a poor job, but most of the information comes from interviews with **Miyazaki Hayao**

To sum it up, basically **Miyazaki Hayao** is saying that your name is something that defines you through out your life and as I stated earlier being that Chihiro is now in the spirit world that she starts to forget about the living world. When Yubaba takes those other kanji all that is left is **「千, せん = sen」**, this is what Chihiro's name will become in the spirit world if she ends up staying there forever. So she will effectively forgot everything about her life of the living. who she was, her parents and basically everything she ever knew. Hence the reason for the other Kanji disappearing, having a symbolic message that she will lose herself in the spirit world.

Edit: Another interesting thing I found out was that b/c she "misspelled" her name in Kanji that her contract with Yuubaba was never actually binding and that was the reason why she was able to return to the real world.　And was also the reason that Haku was never able to return to the real world as he used his real name and his contract was binding.

And I am guesing that is why the movie is named this  **「千 と 千尋 の 神隠し」** in Japanese. Emphasis on 「**千** と **千尋**」.

**Miyazaki Hayao** gives some really deep messages, unfortunately it is not easily translated into something that an English speaker, well whit a short answer like this anyway.

Comment: I watched a video today that mentioned most names in the movie to have literal translations. Like, Yubaba meant *hot water*. Does Chihiro or Sen have meanings?

Comment: @BlueMoon93, I edited my answer abut Chihiro's name meaning. And `Yubaba`, does not mean hot water. It is broken down like this, `Yu-baba`, `Yu` meaning hot-spring/Bath-house in this case (Can mean hot water) and `baba` meaning old hag. So it means the 'Bath house hag` in a none literal translation.

Comment: Yubaba is a pun. There is a Russian folk tale of Yubaba, a witch. But in Japanese "Yuu" is hot water (as used in baths) and "baba" is a childish way of saying grandmother. Hence the pun. Look also at the scene when sen is "clocking in" for the first time. All the other workers have shortend names. Haku's name has also been shortened.

Comment: If I'm careful with my long and short vowels: Obaasan is grandmother, Obasan is aunt, baa means old lady (without the honorifics). baaba is a childish way of referring to their grandmother see wwwjdic ばあば. The Russian witch is Yubaba, but the character in Sen is Yuubaaba.

Comment: @JamesK, I am talking about `babaa` https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%83%90%E3%82%A2 which is not what children call their grandparents. This is what `Yubaba` is referring to.

Comment: @JamesK, I should have said `Yubabaa` in English.

Comment: Chihiro's error changes one of the three components of that character from ‘fire’ to ‘dog’, hmm. — And now I learn that the component beside it is a reduced form of ‘dog’.

Answer (score 4):

The four symbols are Chihiro's Name, the first two are her family name, the second two are her given name: "Chihiro". The symbols are "Chinese characters" since Japanese uses the writing system of China (much as English uses the writing system of the Romans)

Chinese characters often have several pronunciations in Japanese. The context is important in knowing how to read a Chinese character. The character 千 (meaning "thousand") is pronounced "sen" on its own, but "chi" as part of the name "千尋" Chihiro. Learning how to read kanji in context is one of the challenges of reading Japanese.

When a person asks Yubaaba for work she is compelled to offer them a job but controls them by stealing their name. When the Kohaku river was redirected to culverts and sewers, the god of the river, having nowhere else to go, came to Yubaaba and asked to become her apprentice. She stole his full name "Nigihayami Ko**haku** Nushi", and he became Haku, and subject to her will. She tries to steal Chihiro's name, but fails as Chihiro has the goodbye card from her old school friend.

There is a scene, on Sen's first day at work, when she has to turn her name tag over, to show she is present for work. You can see the other names that workers have. Some are single Chinese characters. A tall humanoid woman behind Sen turns over the tag lablled "口" (kuchi) meaning "mouth". She must have also had her full name stolen. On the other hand, "Rin" has her name written phonetically, as "リン".